# update the value of metric in streamlit using session_state

Tags: python, pandas, session-state, streamlit

I have streamlit app where i load a dataframe with the ability to filter and return data based on the user input. I have a function that return the number of returned records using `df.shape[0]`.

What i want is to change the **displayed number of records** based on the return result by the user filter. so i did use for the `st.session_state`  but it seems i misused.

## code:

```
def metric_employee(df):
    
    if "df" in st.session_state:
        return df['status_type'].value_counts()["employee"]
    st.session_state.df=pd.DataFrame(df,columns= df.columns)
    return st.session_state.df

result = df    
col1_m,col2_m,col3_m = st.columns(3)
    #  use session state to display number corresponding to the result table!!!!!!!!
    with col1_m:
        st.markdown(
            f'<p class = "employee_metric"> {metric_employee(result)} employee</p>',
            unsafe_allow_html= True,
        )

if radioDB=="Search":  
        regular_search_term=st.sidebar.text_input("Enter Search Term")
        if st.sidebar.button("search",key=1):    
            result = df[df['name'].str.contains(regular_search_term)|
            df['nickname'].str.contains(regular_search_term)|
            df['mother_name'].str.contains(regular_search_term)]

            st.write(f"{str(result.shape[0])} Records ")
            display_aggrid(result)
```

**st.write(f"{str(result.shape[0])} Records ")**

the statement above display the total returned result
what i want in my metric is to display the number of records in column status_type where the cell value is employee , and i want to change this number each time the user filter the dataframe.

so what is my mistake and how to change the number based on the returned results?

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
def metric_employee(df):
    """
    Returns the number of records on column status_type with
    employee value from the given df.
    """
    dfe = df.loc[df['status_type'] == 'employee']
    return len(dfe)
```

Comment: based on your answer the returned number in the metric will always stay the same.

what i want is to change this number each time the filter is done

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: still this did not work as i want because let say the **total number of employees is 200** after i filter the dataframe it return **50 records** based on my input ... so from these 50 there are **30 records as employee** here the metric must display **30** but in your answer it still displaying **200**

Comment: I thought that the `df` in `metric_employee(df)` is already a filtered df. Could you write a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: No its not a filtered `df` that is the problem  like i want to make the metric dynamic it change on every filter

Comment: If you can post a reproducible code, this is easier to solve.